# Does Science Say That We Should Die?

Tags: human-biology, mammals, speculative, organs

Excluding situations where you die from accidents, the main reason for death is -generaly- [diseases](http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs310/en/).

And usually it is about an organ which becomes "tired" after many years. These results are all from experience and statistics:

[image: Top 10 causes for death]

But I've never heard of any study that said: "people can't live longer than x age because the heart can't live longer than that".

From my point of view, I think it's us who control the way we live and consequently someone can live longer than the other. For example, [smokers die at an early age.](http://www.lung.org/stop-smoking/about-smoking/facts-figures/general-smoking-facts.html)

But even the [oldest person in the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_verified_oldest_people), lived for 122 years and 164 days. For me this isn't enough. It seems that someone can't control his age after all.

Basically my question is: Does science provide any limit that a person isn't able to live more than it? For instance can someone live more than 1000 years?

---

<sub><sub>Note: I don't think someone is able to do this because simply even our healthiest habits are not "so" healthy. But imagine someone who doesn't live like any of us as humans, i.e. Can have a very healthy and natural life</sub></sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting a great biologist Peter Medawar :

> It is by no means difficult to imagine a genetic endowment which can
>   favor young animals only at the expense of their elders; or rather at
>   their own expense when they, themselves, grow old. A gene or
>   combination of genes that promotes this state of affairs will, under
>   certain numerically definable conditions, spread throughout a
>   population simply because the younger animals it favors have, as a
>   group, a relatively large contribution to make to the ancestry of the
>   future population.

From Why We Get Sick :

> Imagine that there is a gene that changes calcium metabolism so that
>   bone heals faster, but the same gene also causes slow and steady
>   calcium deposition in the arteries. Such a gene might well be selected
>   for, because many individuals will benefit from its advantages in
>   youth, while few will live long enough to experience the disadvantage
>   of arterial disease in old age. Even if the gene caused everyone to
>   die by age 100, it would still spread if it offered even minor
>   benefits in youth. This argument does not depend on the prior
>   existence of senescence. Other causes of death—accidents, pneumonia,
>   and all the rest—are sufficient to reduce the population at older
>   ages. Nor does the theory depend, like Haldane’s, on cessation of
>   reproduction.

The message I am trying to get across is that - As organisms are like vehicles which carry DNA and DNA just "madly" wants to replicate itself and pass itself from generation to generation, Natural Selection will favour those traits that maximise reproductive success. These may be traits that provide maximum benefit in youth but cause gradual damage and lead to senescence and death.

You could also think like this - Every machine has wear and tear and must be thrown away after it is irreparable. Same is with our body, it is the most beautiful machine in the world but it is also subject to the same wear and tear.

Also there is the end replication problem. See telomeres if you dont know what I am talking about. There is a limit to number of times a cell can divide.

So all in all I would say that there is a biological limit - a certain age up to which a person may live.

Comment: If you want more examples of such traits see [this](http://health.tipsdiscover.com/aging-as-the-fountain-of-youth-why-do-we-age/) where the chapter on  ageing from the book Why We Get Sick is available.